# I need help setting a grub theme!

Tags: grub2, 20.04, themes

I did the following 1. CD Downloads 2. CD VIMIX-1080p 3. ./install.sh 4. The installation happened! Then I reboot to find out that the theme did not apply I also checked the themes folder but that seemed to be empty! I dont get why the theme has not worked!

Ubuntu 20.04 grub 2

Comment: From where did you download the script? `/etc/default/grub` is owned by root, did you run script with sudo? What is the output of `grep GRUB_THEME /etc/default/grub`?

Answer (score 0):

the easiest way is to install grub customizer
by

```
sudo apt install grub-customizer
```

it will allow you to
change

1. background of grub such as a color or a image
2. it will allow to change color of the text in grub
   and more

Comment: Sadly though, I cant get the background image to work either!

Comment: what is the image can you post it also what is resolution of the image

Comment: Image: https://wallpaperhub.app/wallpapers/1534
Resolution: 1080p

Comment: oh i found the error grub2 doesnt work well with jpeg compressed image

Comment: wait i will convert it to .png image format and upload it will take a minute

Comment: here you go this will work on grub https://drive.google.com/file/d/15_5kfB8eSc32c5RwsVbf7uQAJ42nK1f7/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks for all the support in which you provided!

Comment: That image did not show up as the grub menu background!

Comment: have you saved your grub configuration in grub customizer

Comment: Yes, I have saved it!